# unable to load pyspark under anaconda

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I have installed pyspark (pyspark-2.3.1-py37_1.tar). when I try to import, I get this error:

```
[bin]$ ./conda list | grep -i spark
    pyspark                   2.3.1                    py37_1    <unknown>

[bin]$ ./python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  1 2018, 23:32:55)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest downloading the actual Apache Spark tarball package, then run `pyspark` out of that.

Comment: I do have export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7" set up, still not working

Comment: Have you tried running `$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark` ?

Comment: I installed pyspark under anaconda distribution. The package is there, when I try to import it in junyper notebook, import error.

Comment: I have never used Anaconda, but it sounds like your Jupyter Kernel is pointing at the wrong Python version where you have installed Spark into

Comment: As @cricket_007 has suggested, before trying with Jupyter, see first if you can run it in the command line with `$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark`

Comment: SPARK_HOME directory was set wrong in my path. I corrected the path in bashrc file and now it works fine. Thanks everybody for their input.